How to Access Token Metadata Program ID on Localnet?
On devnet, testnet, and mainnet, the program ID metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s is readily available. However, I can't find this program ID on my localnet. I'm running a local Solana test validator and need to work with the Token Metadata Program for development and testing purposes.
Is it possible to make a dump the metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s program and run it locally using solana-test-validator?

You can download the mainnet MPL Token Metadata program using
solana program dump --url mainnet-beta metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s metadata.so

Load your validator with the downloaded program and start it using
 solana-test-validator --bpf-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s metadata.so

However this will not download the history for the program and load it locally. You can create ixs that interact with the metadata project for that

when I run solana-test-validator it informed that --bpf-program argument ignored, ledger already exist. So I still can't find there.

delete the test-ledger fille if present and try again

oh right, works well.
